# Scaling of "non-reduced" parameters in RG theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, phase-transition, dimensional-analysis, ising-model

I'm studying quantum phase transitions using the Renormalization Group (RG) method. In Continentino's book "*Quantum Scaling in Many-Body Systems: An Approach to Quantum Phase Transitions*" the 1D Ising model is treated and the author claims that under an RG step the parameters rescale as:
\begin{equation}
J'=b^{-y}J \qquad h'=b^{-y}h \qquad g'=b^ag
\end{equation}
where $J$ is the spin coupling, $h$ the transverse field and $g=h/J-(h/J)_c$.

It is not clear to me why $J$ and $h$ should rescale as stated. The scaling of the parameters comes from linearizing the renormalization operator $R_b$ *around the fixed point*. In the case of $h/J$ there is indeed a fixed point $(h/J)_c$, but this is not the case for $J$ and $h$ *alone*, isn't it? Shouldn't the ratio be the thing that matters?

In all the references I found the RG flow is studied with respect to $h/J$, I could find no mention of the rescaling of the parameters $h$ and $J$ independently.